# Isuues executing form inside wordpress plugin page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am quite a novice when it comes to coding/development. Especially when it comes to wordpress. I have managed to cobble together a plugin for my job that will use intervention.io to create all product images on different apparel with the uploaded image and then create a product and use those images to create product variations.

So far I have managed to get the image manipulation part of the script to work outside of Wordpress. When I transfer my code to my Wordpress plugin I get a few issues.

My Wordpress main page contents:

```
<form action="/test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="pname">Product Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname"><br><br>

  <b>APPAREL:</b><br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="tshirt" name="apparel[]" value="tshirt">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="tshirt"> T-Shirt</label>
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="longsleeve" name="apparel[]" value="longsleeve">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="longsleeve"> Longsleeve</label>
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="sweater" name="apparel[]" value="sweater">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="sweater"> Sweater</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="beanie" name="apparel[]" value="beanie">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="beanie"> Beanie</label>
  
  <br><br>
  
    <b>SIZES:</b><br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="size_small" name="size[]" value="size_small">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="size_small"> Small Size</label>
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="medium_size" name="size[]" value="medium_size">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="medium_size"> Medium Size</label>
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="large_size" name="size[]" value="large_size">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="large_size"> Large Size</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="xlarge_size" name="size[]" value="xlarge_size">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="xlarge_size"> X Large Size</label>
  
    <br><br>
  
    <b>COLORS:</b><br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="white_color" name="color[]" value="white_color">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="white_color"> White</label>
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="black_color" name="color[]" value="black_color">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="black_color"> Black</label>
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="red_color" name="color[]" value="red_color">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="red_color"> Red</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="blue_color" name="color[]" value="blue_color">
  <label class="ikc_apparel_form_option" for="blue_color"> Blue</label>
  
  
<p>
    <label for="pic">Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="pic" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</p>
</form>
```

1st Question) After the form is submitted on the WordPress plugin page, how do I get my test.php file to run in the WordPress environment or on another plugin page. It currently runs on a blank white page.

2nd Question) I also have to define the absolute path of test.php now. Am I supposed to change the form action or is this just normal with WordPress?

Comment: 1st - the code you have showd is probably the OUTPUT code . It can not be a WP page code. 2nd - you should really have a look at wordpress plugin development. ( google is your best friend here )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.